# If you had an indestructible disk, where would you place it to block the most energy from the sun?

Tags: optics, astronomy

Imagine you have an indestructible, opaque disk, (say 100m in diameter), and you want to place it between the sun and the earth to block the most energy from hitting the earth.

Some assumptions:

1. We don't worry about mismatched orbital speeds, it will always stay directly between the earth and the sun.
2. The disk doesn't radiate any of the energy it absorbs.

My intuition says that it should be much closer to the earth than the sun, but I can't justify why. Which concepts will I need to apply in order to determine the optimal position?

Comment: I guess you can't ignore the finite extent of the sun or earth. The answer will in general depend on the radius of the sun, earth and disk. I think you'll also need to perform integrals over the surface of the sun and earth. Sounds ugly.

Comment: A 100 m disc in orbit isn't going to block much sunlight. At an altitude of 100 km it has the the same angular diameter as a 1 mm disc at 1 m.

Comment: What could make this problem less 'homework-like'? It's definitely not a homework question, I was just wondering this the other day and it's been 6 years since I took physics.